# Form not posting when jquery event attached to submit button

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm a novice at coding, but I'm trying to show a thank you for subscribing message after a form is submitted by using jquery to add a class to the div container that holds the form to hide it using display:none and adding a thank you message in its place. I'm using the code below:

```
$('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').submit(function(){
    var element = document.getElementById("newsletterform");
    element.classList.add("success");
    element.innerHTML += '<div class="thanks">Thanks for Subscribing!</div>';
    $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').submit();
});
```

Here is the html

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .success{
        group_input{
            display:none;
        }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <iframe name="votar" style="display:none;"></iframe> 
    <div id="newsletterform">
    <form action="{{ settings.mailchimp_form_action }}" method="post" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" target="votar">

    <div class="group_input">
      <input type="text" value="" name="COMPANY" class="" id="mce-COMPANY">
      <input type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="{{ settings.news_input }}" /><button  class="btn" type="submit">{{settings.news_actiontext}}</button>
    </div>       
    </form>
    </div>

</body>
```

This hides the form and shows the thank you message, but it doesn't submit the email address. It's like the email was stripped before posting to the action url.

I also tried moving `$('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').submit();` above the var declaration and it submits the form with the email address, but the thank you message does not show.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: please add a [`MCVE`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: what happens if you remove this line `$('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').submit();`

Comment: shreyas - it just displays the thank you text without submitting the form

Comment: There is no #mc-embedded-subscribe-form

Comment: Ajay Sorry, fixed

Answer (score 0):

Try submitting the form via ajax :

```
$("form#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        success: function(data)
        {
            var element = document.getElementById("newsletterform");
            element.classList.add("success");
            element.innerHTML += '<div class="thanks">Thanks for Subscribing!</div>';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That submits the form, but the class does not get added nor the html appended

Comment: tried jquery  ? `$('#newsletterform').addClass('success').append('<div class="thanks">Thanks for Subscribing!</div>');`

Comment: Do you mean to replace the success function with this jquery $('#newsletterform').addClass('success').append('<div class="thanks">Thanks for Subscribing!</div>');?

Comment: Were you able to solve it ? Please update how you solved it.